# Trouble connecting UART device via USB Port

Tags: ttyusb, gpsd

Im trying to communicate with a couple of UART devices via USB. A HT-06 bluetooth module and a GY-NEO6MV2 GPS module. I am using a Prolific PL2303 USB cable. As a backup I also have a Silicon Labs CP2102.

When I connect the PL2303

- a `lsusb` command returns

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 015: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
  ```
- and a `dmesg` command returns

  ```
  [147697.657037] usb 1-11: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
  ```
- a `ls -l` of `/dev` shows

  ```
  crw-rw----  1 root dialout   188,   0 Jun 15 08:58 ttyUSB0
  ```

and I've added myself to the `dialout` group as well as setting `chmod` to `666`.

I then use Putty with a serial connection with Port `/dev/ttyUSB0`, Baud 9600 and Parity 8,1,None. I connect the PL2303 cable to the HT-06 as GND-GND, VCC-VCC, TX-RX and RX-TX. All pretty basic stuff.

The Putty screen starts with a cursor in the top left corner. I send an AT command. Im expecting OK but nothing happens. I have a second HT-06, but still nothing.

I thought it might be a broken RX or TX Cable (I get a flashing LED on the HT-06 so VCC and GND are OK) so I swapped out the PL2303 for the CP2102. Both lsusb and dmesg tell me the converter is connected (again at `/dev/ttyUSB0`). Using the same Putty settings I still get nothing.

Along similar lines Ive connected the NEO6M  with both the PL2303 and the CP2102, and use `xgps` (a subset of `gpsd`). This returns an error

```
gpsd is not connected to /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and obviously nothing happens.

Im using Linux Mint 20 with kernel 5.4.0-74-generic which has the drivers for both CP210X and PL230X. Ive also tried different USB ports (USB2 and USB3)
Despite 2 different USB-TTL converters, 3 UART devices and several different serial terminal apps (Ive also tried `minicomm` and `rfcomm`), nothing works.

Comment: ff you're on a Linux system  regarding the gpsd, type "systemctl status gpsd" and it will tell you which port gpsd is *trying* to connect to. The error may be because your cable is connected to a different port.  See the configuration file /etc/default/gpsd file. If you want to use the bluetooth usb dongle, install the needed bluetooth software.

Comment: the port is correct at /dev/ttyUSBO. the problem is it wont connect which is the essense of my question

Comment: How are the CFG_COM0 and CFG_COM1 pins configured on the GY-NEO6MV2? And with "HT-06", do you mean ForceTronics HC-06 or something else?

Comment: The CFG_Com0&1 are NMEA, 9600, Bus Powered and the standard sentences (GSA,GSV,RMC etc) I have (as you pointed out) mistyped the bluetooth. It is HC-06 and NOT HT-06. They are both JY-MCU

Comment: @griza: it you want any further help, please post the output of "systemctl status gpsd" - just cut and paste  the ouput - no images.

Comment: ● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-06-15 12:53:11 AEST; 22h ago
TriggeredBy: ● gpsd.socket
    Process: 44200 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd $GPSD_OPTIONS $DEVICES (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 44213 (gpsd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19026)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
             └─44213 /usr/sbin/gpsd

Comment: un 15 12:53:11 geoff-desktop systemd[1]: Starting GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon...
Jun 15 12:53:11 geoff-desktop systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.

Answer (score 0):

can you share your tty configuration stty --all -F /dev/ttyUSB0 and check the CLOCAL flag, check for all the configuration flags, also check your hardware configuration there are different wiring configuration for the DB9 connector. also remember that the speed is baud rate or bit rate(depending on the driver configuration). So if you want a bit rate of 9600 sometimes you should set the speed to 1200

Answer (score 0):

I dug out an old Arduino that has worked previously on my PC when it was a much older version of Linux.
With the latest Arduino IDE and Serial Monitor... It works. I can now communicate with Both HC-06 and NEO6m Devices.
Not the resolution I was after, but its a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I've got my modem to work by using `picocom` (`sudo apt install picocom`) program:

```
picocom /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then just type commands. Also, try it with sudo if it doesn't work.